# Child Process, JSON Serialization double quotes missing at receiver end

Tags: c#, .net, process, json.net, arguments

I have an application which creates a new process (child process) for executing a long-running job. I need to pass the `JSON` string as an argument's value to the `child process` from the `parent process`.

As per my observation, from `logs` while debugging, found that the `serialization` output looks good but at the receiver end in the child process the *double quotes* are missing! and this results in failing to deserialize.

`JSON` string after serialization, before passing as an argument to process

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}
```

`JSON` string at the receiver end of the child process

```
{key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3,key4:value4}
```

Serialization method, using `NewtonSoft` library,

```
    string GetStringData(ProcessJobModel pjm)
    {
        string jobDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pjm, Formatting.None); 
        return jobDataString;
    }
```

Passing as value to the child process,

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = GetStringData(pjm);
```

I am assuming we should be able to pass serialized JSON data since the argument only takes a string value. I might be missing something here, would be thankful to anyone who can guide me here.

Comment: try `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + GetStringData(pjm) + "\"";`

Comment: @viveknuna tried that, but didn't work. same error.

Comment: The process you are sending this data to is also a .NET application?

Comment: try to use Base64 encoding. Serialize and encode your object so you won't have to deal with quotes escaping and so on.

Comment: @Evk yes both are .NET applications, `framework v 4.7.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single argument that includes spaces must be surrounded by quotation marks, but those quotation marks are not carried through to the target application. To include quotation marks in the final parsed argument, you must use `triple-escape` for quote each mark.
From the .NET documentation,

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myApp1.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "/a /b:\"\"\"quoted string\"\"\"";
```

However, passing JSON via this approach to another executable is very error-prone. Instead you must write the JSON to some temporary file and only pass the path of that file to the called executable. Because, even if you encode it and pass, only max length of 32kb can be passed via this `Arguments` property.